# dynamic url in an asset() methode in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I wrote this code in a laravel blade but the pictures are not shown
src="{{asset('produits/'.$produit->photo_principale)}}"
how can I fix it

Comment: where did you put this picture? what file path

Comment: in public/produits

Comment: does the web server have read access to the file?

Answer (score 0):

try `php artisan storage:link` if its not working please be more specific! :)

Comment: I want to concatinate .$table->attribute to the asset() methode . the attribute in my case is the name of the picture

Comment: if you dump `$produit->photo_principale)` what does it return?

Comment: "tomate.jpeg" witch is the name of the wanted file

Comment: perfect, then you have found the error. Make sure you have that property assigned in the model.

Comment: would you please tell me how to verify this ... I am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Dear community I found my error and it's a little bit shaming ... in order to type .jpg I wrote the wrong extention .jpeg and then my pictures are showing up